# Question regarding general formula for propagation of errors in functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, calculus, error-analysis

The question regarding which i am asking this question is as follows

> In an experiment for determination of the focal length of a thin convex lens, the distance of the object from the lens is $10 \pm 0.1cm$ and the distance of its real image from the lens is $20 \pm 0.2cm$. The error in the determination of focal length of the lens is $n\%$. The value of $n$ is.

Here is how i approached the question the function for the focal length can be written as follows

$$f = f(u, v) = \frac{uv}{u-v}$$

Where $u$ is the object distance and $v$ is the image distance.

And the general formula for propagation of errors is as follows

$$\delta F(x,y)^2 = (\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}\cdot \delta x)^2 + (\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\cdot\delta y)^2$$

Therfore for the above function it should be as follows
$$\delta F(u,v)^2 = (\frac{\partial F(u,v)}{\partial u}\cdot \delta u)^2 + (\frac{\partial F(u,v)}{\partial v}\cdot\delta v)^2$$
Computing the required derivatives we get the following equation
$$(-\frac{v^2}{(u-v)^2}\cdot \delta u)^2 + (\frac{u^2}{(u-v)^2}\cdot\delta v)^2$$

Now plugging in the values to the above equations for $u$ and $v$, and $\delta u = 0.1$ and $\delta v = 0.2$

$$\frac{20^4}{10^4} \cdot (0.1)^2 + \frac{10^4}{10^4}\cdot(0.2)^2 = \frac{1}{5}$$

Therefore,
$$\delta F(x,y)^2 = 1/5$$
$$\delta F(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$\delta F(x,y) = 0.447$$

However the answer to the above question is $1\%$ for some reason.

Due to the complexity of the calculation i am pretty sure i am using some wrong formula or something else as i have checked the derivatives and calculations, could someone please point me in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why is your formula not $uv/(u+v)$?  Both $u$ and $v$ are positive quantities, right?  Also, $\delta F$ is the absolute error.  You should divide by the focal length (6.7 cm?) to determine the relative error.  I get an error of about 7% but I could have made a mistake too.

Comment: Well the formula for focal length is 1/f = 1/v - 1/u

Comment: No...http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenseq.html, some sources may quote that formula if they're talking about negative image distances, but here you have a positive image distance.

Comment: Your value as presented in your working is actually 2.2%; I can get the answer's 1.1% if we ignore some corrections that you are actually doing a better job thereof. But I agree with quantumwave that it ought to be the other formula. Clarify that, or we cannot get anywhere.

Comment: oh ok let me check the calculation using wolfram alpha

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent the question is from a exam where the method i am usnig is not used what ignoring of corrections do you suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808402/2451