# Question regarding error analysis of focal length of a lens

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, error-analysis, statistics

The question in whose context i am asking this question is as follows

> In an experiment for determination of the focal length of a thin convex lens, the distance of the object from the lens is $10 \pm 0.1\hspace{1mm}cm$ and the distance of its real image from the lens is $20 \pm 0.2\hspace{1mm}cm$. The error in determination of the focal length is $n\%$. The value for $n$ is_________.

Now in the offical solution for the above question the following answer is given

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{v} - \frac{1}{u}$$
$$\frac{\Delta f}{f^2} = \pm(\frac{\Delta v}{v^2} + \frac{\Delta u}{u^2})$$
$$\frac{\Delta f}{f} = \pm(\frac{\Delta v}{v^2} + \frac{\Delta u}{u^2})f$$
$$\pm(\frac{0.2}{20^2} + \frac{0.1}{10^2}) \times \frac{20}{3}$$
$$\frac{\Delta f}{f} = 0.01$$
$$\frac{\Delta f}{f} \times 100 = 1%$$

I have various problems with this solution first of all from where does the error of the focal length come from the mirror formula should one not use differentiation to solve this.

If we can use differentiation how?, could someone please point me in the right direction on how to solve this question using the general formula for error which is as following.

$$\delta F(x,y)^2 = (\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x} \cdot \delta x)^2 + (\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\cdot\delta y)^2$$

Any help would highly be appreciated!

Comment: As mentioned before, that is a crappy approximation, and your proper differentiation result is actually much better than this.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent could you please explain to me how this "crappy approximation" works, as using the proper differentiation method does not give the right answer according to the test.

Are their certain assumptions we have to make to reach the crappy approximation, if their are please point me in the right direction.

As the test uses this method of solution

Comment: Im quite certain that any test has to accept your much more proper answer, along with any approximation that they also do accept. If they do not, go and lodge a formal complaint. I'll type it up for you. Wait a bit.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent well i will try but could u please give me how we could approach this crappy approximation by making certain assumptions as my test is round the corner and sending in a email email and waiting for a reply would take time.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808208/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues here. Firstly you're asking how differentiation is being used here, and secondly you correctly point out that errors should be added in quadrature.

Let's take the second issue first: you are correct that if the errors are normally distributed and if our equation is:

$$ a = b + c $$

then the standard deviation in $a$ is given by adding the standard deviations in $b$ and $c$ in quadrature:

$$ \sigma_a{}^2  = \sigma_b{}^2 + \sigma_c{}^2 $$

and the solution is just adding the errors not adding in quadrature. However in introductory discussions of error analysis it's common to just add (the modulus of) the errors i.e.

$$ \Delta a = \Delta b + \Delta c $$

and that is what the solution is doing. This overestimates the error, but in most cases it still gives a reasonable estimate of the error and in any case we don't know if the errors are normally distributed or not.

Anyhow, now on to how differentiation is being used. The solution *is* using differentiation in the usual way. We have the equation:

$$ g = \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} $$

where $g = 1/f$ and differentiation gives (adding the moduli of the errors):

$$\begin{align} dg &= \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) du + \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{1}{v}\right) dv \\
&= \frac{du}{u^2} + \frac{dv}{v^2}
\end{align}$$

Then since:

$$ g = \frac{1}{f} $$

we get:

$$ dg = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{1}{f}\right) df = \frac{df}{f^2} $$

Giving the result in the solution;

$$ \frac{df}{f^2} = \frac{du}{u^2} + \frac{dv}{v^2} $$

Comment: Should'nt the derivative of $\frac{1}{u}$ be $\frac{-1}{u^2}$?, or is it because errors are always added you chose to not include the negative sign

Comment: @koiboi Yes, we use the modulus of $\partial f/\partial x_i$ so we just add the terms. I guess I should edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Another question how did you multiply the partial differential terms with $dv$ and $du$

Comment: @koiboi I'm not sure what you are asking. I just used $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x} \cdot \delta x$ as you said in your question.

Comment: Oh sorry!, the notation messed me up.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way could you point me to any resources which would give some motivation for the general formula which i have given above, my prof taught it to me.

Comment: @koiboi any book or web article about error analysis should be fine. I don't have a specific recommendation.

Comment: One thing should the partial differential be of the entire function with respect to $u$ and not just the partial differential of $1/u$

Comment: @koiboi Yes. I just left out the terms that differentiated to zero for clarity.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, you should learn the ways to approach this website. You have two other questions on this site that is actually the same question, and thus you are just asking for these questions to be closed as duplicates. You should be fixing the first question until it can be asked properly. In fact, in a comment, Farcher had already given you the main point that I am about to reproduce.

Your general formula for error propagation is actually a simplification of something more fundamental. The aim in error propagation is *not* to overestimate uncertainty estimates, because if we do so, then we cannot properly model the actual real-world uncertainties. If you overestimate uncertainties, some statistical tests for goodness of fits will fail, and you might be wrongly accused of data fabrication.

The relevant concept for defining the spread of uncertainty around a central value is the *variance.* Let the mean value of a variable $x$ be written as $\bar x$, and let the theoretically expected value thereof $E(x)=\bar x$ i.e. the expected value is the mean value. Then the variance is defined as $\text{Var}(x)=E[(x-\bar x)^2]=\sigma^2_x$

Now, by Taylor's expansion around the mean value,
$$F(x,y)=F(\bar x,\bar y)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\delta x+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\delta y+\cdots$$
so that its variance obeys
$$\text{Var}(F)\approx\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)^2\text{Var}(x)+\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)^2\text{Var}(y)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}E(\delta x\delta y)$$
The last term, having $E(\delta x\delta y)$ is called the covariance term, and it is necessary that $x$ and $y$ have zero covariance in order for us to discard this term. One easy way for a pair of variables to have zero covariance, or at least almost so, is for them to both be independent variables. If, instead, your $x$ and $y$ are correlated, for example by being actually secretly the same variable, then you are actually only having one variable and the proper variance formula with this covariance term will get you the correct solution, whereas wrongly assuming that things are uncorrelated will get you a wrong result. You can easily check this.

With the removal of the covariance term, you should check that the variance I have computed above is exactly the same as the "general formula" that you want to use.

---

Now let $g$ be any nice mathematical function we wish to use. Then
$$\text{Var}[g(F)]=\left(\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dF}\right)^2\text{Var}(F)$$
which reduces, in your notation, to
$$\delta g=\left|\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dF}\right||\delta F|$$

We can thus apply this to get the $\frac{\Delta f}{f^2}$ and $\frac{\Delta u}{u^2}$ and $\frac{\Delta v}{v^2}$ terms, each individually.

The problem is that when combining $x\pm y$, it should be $(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2$, which means that the correct solution should have
$$\frac{(\Delta f)^2}{f^4}=\frac{(\Delta v)^2}{v^4}+\frac{(\Delta u)^2}{u^4}$$
which also explains the random appearance of the plus minus sign in the answer key.

However, the professor was lazy, and used $\Delta x+\Delta y$, so that there is a discrepancy between your answer and his answer. Again, this is purely them making a lazy approximation, and so your earlier answer ought to be accepted.